# Matplotlib subplot using for loop Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Trying to create multiple charts and save it as one image. I managed to combine multiple charts but there is couple things that going wrong. Could not set tittles for all charts only for last one for some reason. Also numbers is not showing in full as last chart. Also want to change colors for line(white), labels(white), background(black) and rotate a date so it would be easily to read it. [image]

```
dataSet = {"info":[{"title":{"Value":[list of data]}},{"title":{"Value":[list of data]}}, 
...]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(22, 10), dpi=70, 
linewidth=0.5)
ax = np.array(ax).flatten()

for i, data in enumerate(dataSet['info']):
    for key in data:
        df: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data[key]).fillna(method="backfill")
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms')
        df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
        x = df['Date']
        y = df['Value']
        ax[i].plot(x, y)
    current_values = plt.gca().get_yticks()
    plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in current_values])
    plt.title(key)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Use `plt.gca().set_title` instead of `plt.title` to set all subplot titles.

Comment: I suggest getting familiar with the [differences between pyplot and object oriented axis programming](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/). The methods are often similar but not always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your figure consists of the various axes objects. To set the title for each plot you need to use the corresponding axes object, which provides the relevant methods you need to change the appearance.
See for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)

titles = list("abcd")

for ax, title in zip(axarr.ravel(), titles):
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = np.random.random(10)
    ax.plot(x, y, color='white')
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_facecolor((0, 0, 0))
    
fig.tight_layout()
```

In order to change labels, show the legend, change the background, I would recommend to read the documentations.
For the dates, you can rotate the labels or use `fig.autofmt_xdate()`.